# Is there a way to remove wp-login.php alias (login)?

Tags: login

I recently was looking at my web server logs, and I saw something like this:

```
"GET /login HTTP/1.1" 301 448 "-" "Python-urllib/2.7"
"GET /login HTTP/1.1" 302 4563 "-" "Python-urllib/2.7"
"GET /wp-login.php HTTP/1.1" 403 3982 "-" "Python-urllib/2.7"
```

My wordpress installation is a little bit different, and I use certificates to protect the `wp-login.php` file and `wp-admin` directory. So without the certificate, you will be redirected to the main page, unless you are a bot like in this case.

The solution works fine, but I want to eliminate the extra queries you see above. So the question is how to remove the `login` alias, so the login page would appear only when you type `wp-login.php`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the result of a [default action](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/2ccd9b46dd27619795b27b693398e12426bacca5/wp-includes/default-filters.php#L430), so you can remove it in a plugin with:

```
remove_action( 'template_redirect', 'wp_redirect_admin_locations', 1000 );
```

You could also just block `Python-urllib` in your server configuration.