# How to modify the Wordpress comes with redirect

Tags: redirect, login

I found by **domain.com/login** or **domain.com/admin** will be redirected to **domain.com/wp-admin**, how do I modify them.

Comment: What do you mean modify them? What is the end result of what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

This happens ins the function `wp_redirect_admin_locations()`, and there is no filter in that function to modify the values.

However, you can either just [unhook that function](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/235915/73) and replace it your own function, or leave it as it is and add some additional shorthands in your own callback.

For the custom callback, use the filter `404_template` like in this example:

```
add_filter( '404_template', function( $template ) {
    $request = trim( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/' );

    switch ( $request ) {
        // German
        case 'anmelden':
        case 'einloggen':
        // Spanish
        case 'iniciar':
            wp_redirect( wp_login_url() );
            exit;

        case 'dashboard':
            wp_redirect( admin_url() );
            exit;
    }

    return $template;
});
```